# Java SDK Self Balancing Binary Search Trees

Tags: java

Does the standard Java SDK have a class that represents a Self Balancing Binary Search Trees out of the box?

Answer (score 0):

TreeMap and TreeSet (suppose it just uses TreeMap under the hood)

[TreeMap implements NavigableMap interface and bases it’s internal working on the principles of red-black trees](https://www.baeldung.com/java-treemap)